# Adding a Suffix to a JAR file generated by Maven within Jenkins

Tags: bash, shell, maven, jenkins, rename

I would like to add a suffix to the JAR file created by Maven within Jenkins. The file generated by Maven is called CommandsEX-*.jar, the asterisk is where the version number is. It is easy to simply rename this in Shell/Bash by doing:

```
mv target/CommandsEX-*.jar target/CommandsEX-random-name.jar
```

However the filename will can change, currently it is CommandsEX-2.0.jar. So basically is there a way to get the current file name of a file that you are changing the name of when doing using mv, or maybe another way entirely.

I would use this to add a suffix which would be the $BUILD_ID from Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Maven by specifiying a `classifier`.

http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Maven_Coordinates

Comment: I'm new to Maven & Jenkins, how exactly would I use the classifier to accomplish this?